# Order bar graph in order. In this case, as per days of week

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

[image]

I would like to order the bars as Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday...Sunday instead of a random order. I also would like to display the full numbers on the Y axis instead of 1e+05.

```
#code snippet
DaysCrime <- ggplot(TrainCrime, aes(DayOfWeek))

DaysCrime + geom_histogram(colour = "darkblue", fill = "lightblue")
```

Answer (score 2):

We can convert it to `factor` and specify the `levels` order accordingly.

```
TrainCrime$DayOfWeek <- factor(TrainCrime$DayOfWeek, 
   levels = as.character(wday(c(2:7,1), label=TRUE, abbr=FALSE)))

library(ggplot2) 
DaysCrime <- ggplot(TrainCrime, aes(DayOfWeek))
DaysCrime +
       geom_histogram(colour = "darkblue", fill = "lightblue")
```

#### data

```
v1 <- as.character(wday(1:7, label=TRUE, abbr=FALSE))
set.seed(24)
TrainCrime <- data.frame(DayOfWeek = sample(v1, 100, 
    replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```